# Binding window's background

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I want to bind the background of a window to some string property, such that I'll have a gradient background in different colors when the property changes:

```
<Window.Background>
    <LinearGradientBrush>
        <LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
            <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0"/>
            <GradientStop Color="{Binding Source={RelativeSource Mode=Self}, 
                                          Path=backgroud_color}" Offset="1"/>
        </LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
    </LinearGradientBrush>
</Window.Background>
```

code behind:

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

private string _backgroud_color;
public string backgroud_color
{
   get { return _backgroud_color; }
   set
   {
      _backgroud_color = value;
      OnPropertyChanged("backgroud_color");
   }
}

public void OnPropertyChanged(string property_name)
{
   if (PropertyChanged != null)
      PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property_name));
}
```

but the background does not change at all.
What is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the RelativeSource in the Binding. It'll refer to the GradientStop which doesn't have a backgroud_color Property. Have you set the DataContext for the Window? In that case, you can just bind to backgroud_color like this

```
<Window.Background>
    <LinearGradientBrush>
        <LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
            <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0.5"/>
            <GradientStop Color="{Binding Path=backgroud_color}" Offset="1" />
        </LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
    </LinearGradientBrush>
</Window.Background>
```

Code behind

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.DataContext = this;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can go through the following [link](http://wpf.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=WPF%20Themes&referringTitle=Home)......might find it good to learn and understand basics.....